# Android Async Task Delay [Need Suggestion]

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm am developing an android application that uses AsyncTask.
The problem is the AsyncTask Response is slow, have a quite high delay, so for example by checking if the username and password are correct with the database password because of the delay it would cause the user to login automaticaly without verification or sometimes never login because the information would take too long to come.

Code Example:

```
public JSONArray checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    // URL for getting all customers
    String url = endereco+"/Functions.php?checkLogin=1&username="+username+"&password="+password;
    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log Errors Here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

**How can I bypass the delay?**

Comment: Use some rest clients and check, whether the response time from server is more or less?

Comment: Do you have any control over the code or database on the server you're talking to? It sounds like your database is missing some indexes or something. Ideally, any web service that you're talking to shouldn't have more than a 300 millisecond delay when logging in regardless of how many records there are.

Comment: Back end delay should always be factored into your app.  Allowing the user in by default, because of the delay is a serious problem with your app.  True, the backed need to be optimized, but allowing the user to login without valid credentials is not good.